# Printable PDF output with links as footnotes

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using sphinx to generate the documentation of a python project and I'm making heavy use of  external links. I'd like to build `html` and `latexpdf` outputs with these as clickable links (which is the default), but also a PDF version that will be printed, with these links showing up in footnotes.

In short: is there a way to write external links in a `.rst` file like this:

```
Ask a question on `my favorite Q&A website <http://stackoverflow.com/>`_.
```

and have a special output that will interpret this as if it was a footnote written like this:

```
Ask a question on my favorite Q&A website [#SO]_.

.. [#SO] http://stackoverflow.com/
```

while keeping the normal behavior (clickable link without a footnote) in other outputs?

Comment: Can you work with the solutions mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250659/python-code-to-generate-part-of-sphinx-documentation-is-it-possible? One of the answers mention Sphinx can use custom written extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jongware's comment made me look at parts of the sphinx documentation I didn't see, and I realized there actually is a configuration variable that does what I want:

```py
latex_show_urls = 'footnote'
```

As I wanted to be able to generate the usual pdf and the one with the footnotes without changing the `conf.py` file, I left the default value and added the following rule to the sphinx's Makefile:

```
.PHONY: printpdf
printpdf: SPHINXOPTS+=-Dlatex_show_urls=footnote
printpdf: latexpdf
```

This rule calls the regular `latexpdf` rule, adding `-Dlatex_show_urls=footnote` to the options given to `sphinx-build`.

With this, we can generate the PDF to be printed (with footnotes) with:

```
make printpdf
```

And if we want a regular PDF, without the potentially numerous and (here) useless footnotes, the regular rule still does it:

```
make latexpdf
```

Comment: I hope I made this answer a bit useful, as I feel bad for not seeing the simple option that does just exactly what I wanted…

Comment: @Jongware I'll do it, there's just a two limit before you can accept your own answer.