# footnote as superscript link with reStructuredText and Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is there a way to get Sphinx to generate superscripted links for footnotes that will be represented in HTML like this:

I tried:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur :superscript:`1` adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor :superscript:`[#footnote2]_`
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
```

But the result is just:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <sup>1</sup> adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <sup>[#footnote2]_</sup>
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis

But what I want is:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <sup>1</sup> adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <sup>[4]</sup>
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis

Can this be done?

Comment: Is that a link footnote you want? If so: http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/b20n/python-sphinx-restructuredtext-printable-pdf-output-with-links-as-footnotes and https://stackoverflow.com/q/27656533/1531971 may be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This is done with [footnotes](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#footnotes), and explicitly numbering the footnotes.  Footnote links are automatically superscripted.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur :superscript:`1` adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor [2]_
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis

.. [2] Text of the second footnote.
```

Comment: Superscripting is theme dependent: it is true with `alabaster` and `sphinx_rtd_theme` (Read-the-docs) themes but not with `classic` or `agogo` themes for example.

Comment: @jfbu The rendered HTML has markup that supports superscript styling regardless of theme. `<sup>1</sup>` and `<a class="footnote-reference" href="#id2" id="id1">[2]</a>` are the resulting markup snippets from above. Add custom styles to themes that lack the visual display of superscript.

Comment: Agreed, the mark-up  is there and allows user customization via custom styling. It was only to point out _automatically superscripted_ does not apply out-of-the-box to all themes.