How to programmatically generate some documentation from Python dictionary and insert it into .rst file using Sphinx
I am writing a configuration tool that automates the deployment of some monitoring dashboards. Each dashboard has a written description that is available in the tool, and can be found in the deployed dashboard. But we also have some functional documentation that repeats this description so end-users can read it outside of the code. So basically we have the following:

description_mapping.py

dashboard_description_mapping = {"dashboard_1": "This dashboard achieves xyz"}


README.rst

Templates
=========

Descriptions
------------

* **dashboard_1**
    
    This dashboard achieves xyz

I simplified the approach, in the real case we have many dashboard and descriptions that are all duplicated in the file description_mapping.py and in README.rst.
I would like to have the ability to be able to do some sort of command that gives me the following:
Templates
=========

Descriptions
------------

* **dashboard_1**
   
   .. magic_command: description_mapping.dashboard_description_mapping.get("dashboard_1")

Which would then render as if the description is automagically grabbed, and basically then I don't violate the DRY principle anymore.
Is this possible? I have searched a while, and came across this former question ,but this does not seem to achieve what I need:

How to use Python to programmatically generate part of Sphinx documentation?
Displaying dictionary data in Sphinx documentation

I would like to grab the string, not just print out the whole dictionary basically.
I tried to use existing functionality of ..autodoc, but this did not give me desired output but simply printed out the dictionary.

Please explain what about autodoc did not satisfy your requirement.  In addition, can you elaborate more fully as to exactly what your requirements are?

I thought my example was quite clear, but basically I want to read the contents of a dictionary and be able to grab strings from that dictionary and put it into the documentation. This then means that any change to the dictionary will result in a change in the documentation.

So what part of autodoc didn't do that?

For example I tried to use .. autodata but this did not print it in the way I want. I want to sort of be able to access the values in the mapping dictionary directly so I can print them where I want. And not just print the whole dictionary in an ugly format.

I actually figured out how to do it, I used the custom ..exec directive from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146415/8580574 and basically just printed how I wanted it formatted:
.. exec::
    from title_desc_mappings import dashboard_description_mapping
    
    for key, value in dashboard_description_mapping.items():
        if key.startswith('dashboard'):
            print(f"* **{key}**\n\n")
  
            if value == '':
                print("  No description available.\n")
            else:
                print(f"  {value}\n")

hope this helps someone else
